# Keep all rows with specific text and delete the rest

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this code to delete all rows with specific text in all worksheets. Is there any way that I can keep all rows with specific text and delete the rest? Your help is much appreciated.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

 Dim c As Integer
 Dim n As Integer
 c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
 For n = 1 To c Step 1
    Last = Worksheets(n).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Worksheets(n).Cells(i, "A").Value) = "Oakville" Then
            Worksheets(n).Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
 Next n
 End Sub
```

Comment: `If Worksheets(n).Cells(i, "A").Value <> "Oakville" Then`

Comment: Does your code work? Note to use `Worksheets(n).Rows.Count` as without specifying the worksheet, you will be counting the rows on the active sheet.  Also, wouldn't you just do `If Cells(...).Value <> "Specific Text" Then // ...EntireRow.Delete`?

Comment: @BruceWayne - `Worksheets(n)` does specify the worksheet, by using the Index property of the worksheets class.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Ah, yeah...I meant to point out that `Rows.Count` alone will use the ActiveSheet and it's best to add the worksheet beforehand, i.e. `Worksheets(n).Rows.Count`. Sorry if it was unclear.  (Although I suppose with `Rows.Count`, it doesn't matter what sheet, since it's always the same. It could avoid a possible error though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for example if you want rows with 'Oakville' then just change = to <> in this code itself

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

 Dim c As Integer
 Dim n As Integer
 c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
 For n = 1 To c Step 1
    Last = Worksheets(n).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Worksheets(n).Cells(i, "A").Value) <> "Oakville" Then
            Worksheets(n).Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
 Next n
 End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know how can I add more than one text? It deletes even headings. So I want to add multiple text and heading. For example, don't delete office, oakville, toronto and etc.Can you help with that as well? I tried or but it deleted all rows for some reason :(

Comment: To keep the heading change this step 'i = Last To 1 Step -1' to 'i = Last To 2 Step -1' and keep on adding the words <> with 'And' condition. The query will be like this:-

Comment: Sub WorksheetLoop()

 Dim c As Integer
 Dim n As Integer

 c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

 For n = 1 To c Step 1
    Last = Worksheets(n).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If (Worksheets(n).Cells(i, "A").Value) <> "Oakville" And (Worksheets(n).Cells(i, "A").Value) <> "Toronto" Then
            Worksheets(n).Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
 Next n
 End Sub

Comment: Happy to help:-}

Comment: It seems like this code doesn't work if data is in table format, any thoughts how this code can be adjusted accordingly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143432/discussion-between-india-rocket-and-rovshan-aliyev).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is as below...

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
For Each ws In Worksheets
    LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    LastCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1
    With ws
        .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Formula = "=IF(A1=""Oakville"","""",NA())"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).EntireRow.Delete
        .Columns(LastCol).Clear
    End With
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `AutoFilter` way, no need to loop, no need to worry about the order of deletion and no one-by-one deletion; it removes the undesired rows in one shot. This is definitely my recommended way to do it, give it a try:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   With ws.UsedRange
     .AutoFilter 1, "<>Oakville"
     .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
     .AutoFilter
   End With
Next
```

This conserves "Oakville". Remove those `<>` to remove "Oakville".